# Where can I find detailed crash reports sent by users from a device?

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

I was searching for crash reports sent by users via Android device.

[image: When user clicks on Send Feedback in below image user is taken to another screen]

If the user enters any specific details in description section and clicks Send, where this report is sent? Is it sent to Google or to the developer's email address?

[image]

Comment: you can find that logs in your developer console account portal in section `Android Vitals > ANRs & crashes`

Comment: I wanted to review detailed report where I should be able to see what user has to say in report. In `ANR's & crashes` it's only report of crash details.

Answer (score 1):

You can deduct that the feedback is sent only to Google from two points:

- Below the checkmark for "Include system logs" you'll see them saying that your system info will be sent to Google and a lot of legal policies for data manipulation since the feedback will contain sensitive information.
- Normal crash reports contain information about the stack trace and some device information. If you will check the system info, you'll see a lot of sensitive information, information that Google keeps only for them in order to solve the problem themselves, since sending private information about your user to any developer would not be good idea.

When this kind of crashes take place, it's not your fault(usually) as a developer. If your app crashes constantly, then maybe you should try to open an issue and see what Google has to say about it. For example, the Facebook app crashes on a daily basis for me with the same behaviour, but I didn't find any reason for this.